# HTML Table to JSON

Tags: jquery, html

I need to take table rows and convert to JSON.

Any ideas? I have this code here but it does not work.

```
function tableToJSON(tableID) {
    return $(tableID + "  tr").map(function (row) {
        return row.descendants().pluck("innerHTML");
    }).toJSON();
}
```

Comment: I'll look for a way to do it, but why? HTML tables are a way to display data, not to store it.

Comment: @bigblind it's a pretty common thing, often used when scraping a website, to want to turn data that's not publicly available in any form other than a table, into a usable format, such as JSON.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
function tableToJson(table) {
    var data = [];

    // first row needs to be headers
    var headers = [];
    for (var i=0; i<table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
        headers[i] = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi,'');
    }

    // go through cells
    for (var i=1; i<table.rows.length; i++) {

        var tableRow = table.rows[i];
        var rowData = {};

        for (var j=0; j<tableRow.cells.length; j++) {

            rowData[ headers[j] ] = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML;

        }

        data.push(rowData);
    }       

    return data;
}
```

Taken from [John Dyer's Blog](http://johndyer.name/html-table-to-json/)

Comment: @Awena The author should be credited for their work.

Comment: Seems to be broken with tables that use thead, tbody tags.

Comment: It seems that the answer is an **plagiarism**. Like @John Dyer said, it seems that it came from [johndyer.name/html-table-to-json](http://www.johndyer.name/html-table-to-json/)

Comment: @JohnDyer I have added the link as attribution as it was a direct copy of the code and is against SO's plagiarism policy. Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

I was unhappy with all the solutions above and ended up writing my own jQuery plugin to accomplish this. It is very similar to the solution but accepts several options to customize the results, such as ignoring hidden rows, overriding column names, and overriding cell values

The plugin can be found here along with some examples if this is more what your looking for: https://github.com/lightswitch05/table-to-json

Answer (score 3):

try `$("#"+tableID + "  tr")` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You should find this helpful: http://encosia.com/use-jquery-to-extract-data-from-html-lists-and-tables/

Comment: Browsing to this link thorws this warning.
[![Screen Shot 2017-03-28 at 7.57.30 PM.jpg](https://s13.postimg.org/6km89ehpj/Screen_Shot_2017-03-28_at_7.57.30_PM.jpg)](https://postimg.org/image/x5or4yk2r/)

Answer (score 3):

This one worked for me: (I had only 2 lines in my table, th and td)

```
function htmlToJson(table) {
    var obj = {},
        itemsLength = $(table.find('tbody tr')[0]).find('th').length;
    for (i=0;i<itemsLength;i++) {
        key = $(table.find('tbody tr')[0]).find('th').eq(i).text();
        value = $(table.find('tbody tr')[1]).find('td').eq(i).text();
        obj[key] = value;
    }
    return JSON.stringify(obj)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**HTML table with thead and tbody:**

```
    function htmlTableToJson(table, edit = 0, del = 0) {
        // If exists the cols: "edit" and "del" to remove from JSON just pass values = 1 to edit and del params
        var minus = edit + del;
        var data = [];
        var colsLength = $(table.find('thead tr')[0]).find('th').length - minus;
        var rowsLength = $(table.find('tbody tr')).length;

        // first row needs to be headers
        var headers = [];
        for (var i=0; i<colsLength; i++) {
            headers[i] = $(table.find('thead tr')[0]).find('th').eq(i).text();
        }

        // go through cells
        for (var i=0; i<rowsLength; i++) {
            var tableRow = $(table.find('tbody tr')[i]);
            var rowData = {};
            for (var j=0; j<colsLength; j++) {
                rowData[ headers[j] ] = tableRow.find('td').eq(j).text();
            }
            data.push(rowData);
        }       
        return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
(function($) {

  $.extend($.fn, {

    tableRowsToJSONWithFilter: function(filter) {
      var tableSelector = this,
        item, attr, data, _JSON = [];
      if (typeof(tableSelector) !== 'object') {
        return new Error('Invalid tableSelect!');
      };
      $(tableSelector, 'tr').each(function(index, tr) {
        item = {};
        $('td', $(this)).each(function(index, td) {
          attr = $(td).attr('data-id');
          data = $(td).text();
          if (attr !== undefined && data !== '' && filter && new RegExp(filter, 'i').test(attr)) {
            item[attr] = data;
          };
        });
        _JSON.push(item);
      });
      return _JSON;
    }

  })

})(jQuery);

console.log(
  $('#answered').tableRowsToJSONWithFilter('yodawg')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="answered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-id="user.email">email@email.com</td>
      <td data-id="meme.yodawg">Yo Dog! I Heard you liked answers, so I answered your question, with a method wrapped in a jQuery plugin!</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: useful, and humorous. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one which parses merged rows successfully.

--
Merged rows example:

[image]

-- parse

```js
function tableToJson (table) {
        let data = [];

        // first row needs to be headers
        let headers = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
            headers[i] = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase()
            headers[i] = headers[i]
                .replace(new RegExp('<b>', 'gi'), '')
                .replace(new RegExp('</b>', 'gi'), '')
                .replace(new RegExp('\r?\n', 'gi'), '')
                .trim();
        }

        // go through cells
        for (let i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {

            let tableRow = table.rows[i];
            let rowData = {};
            let rowSpanValue = ''
            if (table.rows[i - 1] && table.rows[i - 1].cells[0].getAttribute("rowspan"))
                rowSpanValue = table.rows[i - 1].cells[0].innerText

            if (!!rowSpanValue)
                rowData[headers[0]] = rowData[headers[0]] || rowSpanValue

            for (let j = 0; j < tableRow.cells.length; j++) {

                let header = !!rowSpanValue ? headers[j + 1] : headers[j]
                let data = tableRow.cells[j]
                let result;
                if (data.querySelector('a')) {
                    result = tableRow.cells[j].querySelector('a').innerText;
                } else {
                    result = tableRow.cells[j].innerText;
                }
                rowData[header] = (rowData[header] || result).replace(new RegExp('\r?\n', 'gi'), '').trim();
            }

            data.push(rowData);
        }

        return data;
    }
```