# extract dynamically an html table updated with php and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

here's my problem, I have written some code that update a table with ajax, after have written it with php:

```
  query = ""

  echo <table>
```

I need to put an input elements after the table generated which extract it with php, it should come something like that:

```
query = ""
row = mysql_fetch_array(query)

echo <div id="table">
     echo <table>
     echo </table>
     echo <input type=submit value=Extract as Excel or CSV>
echo </div>
```

The table is yet updated with an ajax function that run a file like getvalue.php?q=id passed" that change the value in the div making another query.

Well I need the input extract to work but I can't figure out how to pass the query through ajax or php, I can pass the array but it's not what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I read you correctly, you want to send back to the server (to process it into a csv file) the content of an html array which has been modified client side.

One way to do it, would be to extract a json representation of the content of your array and send it back, with ajax, to the server where you'll be able to manipulate it as an array (using json_decode)

This thread should help you with the html table to json part : [HTML Table to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271856/html-table-to-json)

If you just want to generate a csv for the user to download, you can do it entirely on the client side, hence avoiding a roundtrip to the server.

You'll find several exemple online. Here are a few (I haven't tried any of them):

- [exporting data in a table to a csv file](https://gist.github.com/adilapapaya/9787842) (JS only)
- [Export HTML Table to Open Formats](http://quanticalabs.com/ExportHTMLTable/_demo/) (JS & PHP)
- [Full example on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078544/export-to-csv-using-jquery-and-html) (JS only)

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted. Thanks for the reply, I'll try it