# Convert HTML Table into JSON and set new key to JSON

Tags: jquery, json, html-table

I want to convert the data of a html table into json set its key.

```
var tbl = $('#table-availed-prod tr').map(function () {
                    return $(this).find('td').map(function () {
                        return $(this).html();
                    }).get();
                }).get();
```

What I get is this

**JSON** :

[image]

OR

```
Array(){
0: "Sophos"
1: "Complementary"
2: "Codey Ropen"
}
```

What I need is something like this

**JSON** :

```
[{
Productname:"Sophos",
ProductTypename:"Software",
AssignedPerson:"Codey"
},
{
Productname:"Sophos",
ProductTypename:"Software",
AssignedPerson:"Codey"
},
{
Productname:"Sophos",
ProductTypename:"Software",
AssignedPerson:"Codey"
}]
```

**My Table**:
[image: Table Image]

Comment: Similar question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271856/html-table-to-json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach.

```js
var arr1 = [];
var carr = ['product name', 'product type', 'assigned person'];
$("#table-availed-prod tr").map(function(i, tr){
 var arr = {};
 $(this).find('td').map(function(j, td){
       if(carr.indexOf(j) !== -1){
   arr[carr[j]] = $(this).text();
  }
 });
 arr1.push(arr);
});

console.log(arr1);
```